# Drag image files to Photoshop layer

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

I want a fast way to drag an image file to Photoshop and have its content pasted in a new layer in already opened document.
What I do now is opening the image (with dragging) and copying layer to another opened document.
Isn't there a faster way? Similar to Illustrator.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N (new layer), Ctrl+V (paste)?

Comment: I can copy (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+W) a layer from newly opened image (jpg or png) and then paste it directly with Ctrl+V in the desired document. Seems quick, it is, but it could be in one drag & drop. I want to be sure there is no such functionality (or similar), or if there is in CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layer from an existing file

1. Drag the file icon from Windows or Mac OS ***onto*** an open image in Photoshop.
2. Move, scale, or rotate the imported image. (See Place a file in Photoshop.)
3. Press Enter or Return.

By default, Photoshop creates a Smart Object layer.

To create standard layers from dragged files, deselect Place Or Drag Raster Images As Smart Objects in the General preferences.

If the placed file is a multilayer image, a flattened version appears on the new layer. To instead copy separate layers, see Duplicate a layer or group between images.

[(Source)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-78e3a.html)

***Note:*** This was tested in CS5 I am unsure if it works in CS4

Another option would be to use Bridge.  Select multiple files then go Tools > Photoshop > Load File Into Photoshop Layers

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work in CS4 but I know now it works in CS5.